# C++: File lock between threads and processes

Tags: c++, boost, locking, file-locking

I would like to create file based locking that ensures exclusive access of an associated resource. The `boost:interprocess::file_lock` is good for separating processes, but not good for separating threads. That problem can be solved with an additional `boost::recursive_mutex` if we extract the file names to unique full paths (eg. no relatively specified lock files like `something/x.lock`) and associate the mutexes with them.

I would like to have an easier and relatively standard way of file based locking that work for threads and processes alike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [recursive_named_mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_recursive_mutex.html) instead.  Works across processes as well as thread.  A lot cheaper and less error prone to boost.

Comment: Are there any restrictions for the length / content of the name? Where are those mutexes tipically stored? (I know that the point is that I don't have to know)

Comment: Those are operating system implementation details.  You didn't mention your OS.  You could just look at the boost code if you want to find out.

Comment: Why do you suggest a recursive mutex instead of a regular non-recursive one?